# how to increment the values of (0,0,0) in minimal steps to make given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, computational-geometry

According to the question we have given a array **N** of 3 elements lets **[a,b,c]** given a>0 ,b>0,c>0.We have to make a array **X=[0,0,0]** to N by following the given rules . The rules to increment the  X is given by

1. Each time you can increment any two values of X by 1 Eg: [0,1,1] (or) [1,0,1]
2. Incrementing only one value or three values at a time  in X is not allowed
3. you should not increment the values of X to more than the corresponding value in N
4. Count the number of increments you have done on X and return the answer.
5. If we cant make the array X to N . print the  possible array  of X that is nearer to the N  i.e, the  difference between the corresponding elements in the array should be as minimal as possible

Ex:

```
1) given N=[6,6,6]
```

steps:

```
[0,1,1] -> [0,2,2] -> [0,3,3] -> [1,4,3] -> [2,5,3] -> [3,6,3] -> [4,6,4] ->[5,6,5] -> [6,6,6]
```

The number of steps is 9

```
2) given N=[6,6,7]
```

steps:

```
[0,1,1] -> [0,2,2] -> [0,3,3] -> [1,4,3] -> [2,5,3] -> [3,6,3] -> [4,6,4] ->[5,6,5] -> [6,6,6].
```

From here we cannot increment the array because it is violating the rules . The `difference [6,6,7] and [6,6,6] is 1 . so [6,6,6]` is the optimal answer for given N

```
3) given N=[0,0,7]
```

We cannot increment any two values of `X` . so answer is `[0,0,0] for [0,0,7]`

Now is there any method or any direct formula to solve this problem in the efficient way. Thanks in advance . sorry for my poor explanation and title

Comment: The number of steps can be calculated easily with a formula. Have you made any attempt at doing so?

Comment: Yes from last three hours i am trying but unable to solve to it . Can u please explain your formula

Comment: Think about `sum(N)` and how one step affects it.

Comment: By doing sum(N) divided by 2 is not giving correct answer every time. correct me if iam wrong

Comment: You have shown none of your efforts or even thoughts or research in the question. I am voting to close because SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: you want to reach `(a,b,c)` like for instance `(6,6,6)`.
Let factor this into the equation

```
x(1,1,0) + y(1,0,1) + z(0,1,1) = (a,b,c)
```

having `x` being the number of times `(1,1,0)` is applied, and similarly for `y` and `z`. Thus

```
x + y = a
x + z = b
y + z = c
```

giving

```
x = (a + b - c) / 2
y = (c - b + a) / 2
z = (b - a + c) / 2
```

and `x`, `y` and `z` must be all >= 0 and integers.

Result is the sum of `x`, `y` and `z`.

The program to do that is on your side. Hint:

- display a line to ask the user to enter `a`, `b` and `c` (see `printf` and `scanf`)
- calculate the values of `x`, `y` and `z` based on above equations
- check if they're >= 0 and integers (if not display that this isn't possible and stop)
- calculate `x+y+z` and display the result as a solution

Comment: Thanks a lot , I understood now how to proceed further . once again thanks a lot  @ring

Comment: Great! Glad that could help. Suggestion: try to do the program by yourself, and if you have a problem ask another question here, and post your code!